# string grouping algorithm c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, grouping

I need something like a grouping algorithm for strings in C#.
I've tried for days and before I go mad, I should maybe ask someone :)
(no adjazenctmatrix^^)
what do I have is data in an Dictonary

something like this:

```
key|value

"bla","AAA;BBB;CCC" //  ';' is split sign
"whatever","BBB;DDD;EEE;FF"
"hmm", "ZZZ,YYY,XXX"
"foo", "CCC,JJJ,VVV"
....
```

value1 and value2 contains "BBB" so group it to new string : (in a new dictionary,key whatever...counter?)

```
"AAA;BBB;CCC;EEE;FF" (or without distinct to "AAA;BBB;CCC;BBB;DDD;EEE;FF")
```

value3 is his own group

```
value4 contains "CCC" so group it to the others
"AAA;BBB;CCC;EEE;FF;JJJ;VVV" (or without distinct to "AAA;BBB;CCC;BBB;DDD;EEE;FF;CCC;JJJ;VVV")
```

I need that string for SQL update

update item set group = bar
where group in ('','',... )

I do it with split and join, this part works :-P

thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: code formatting.

Comment: *"I need that string for SQL update"* No, you don't. You think you need it but you are probably working with a database that has better ways to pass multiple values than a delimited string, considering the fact that delimited anything in the relational database world is a sign of poor design.

Answer (score 0):

So first organize the data. Have a map `keys["bla"] = some_set("AAA", "BBB", "CCC");` and so on. Then build a reverse map that should look like `reverse["BBB"] = ["bla", "whatever"]` both maps should be about the same size as the original data.

Next you can do a DFS over the implicit graph (pseudocode):

```
merge = some_set()
DFS(string key) {
  if (key in merge) return;  // Been here already.
  merge.insert(key);
  for (string edge : keys[key]) 
    for (string other_key : reverse[edge])
      DFS(other_key)
}
```

So you can now call `DSF("bla")`. When it returns it should contain `"bla", "whatever", ..."` and any other keys that might be in the group and you can concatenate their strings from `keys` to get the result you wanted.

You can call `DFS` for every key to get all the group each key belongs (complexity O(N^2*set_op)). Or, better, keep track of what keys you already processed to avoid working on them again (complexity O(N*set_op)).

If you use hash based sets/maps your set_op is `O(average string length)`. If you use tree based structures then set_op is `O(logN)`. This shouldn't matter unless you have very long strings or lots of keys.